# How conda handle .so of cv2 when --archive to yarn cluster

Tags: python, opencv, hadoop-yarn, conda

We are using cv2 (opencv-python) on worker node in pyspark, so we use `conda pack` and `--archive` to prepare the env via yarn cluster, but we encounter an error during running

```
ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, we check the `environment.zip` generated by `conda pack`, there are many `.so` files in it.

Generally, if the `.so` exists, the solution is to add lib path via system environment variables or add `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` in python 3, but if so, many python packages depended on `.so` file would all raise error, but this is the first time I see this error, which is caused by cv2

`conda pack` use ubuntu 14, yarn os version is ubuntu 16

What is the possible cause? How conda handle the `conda pack` zip file when using yarn cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the answer, it is relative to opencv version

So far, we found `opencv==3.4.2` works